# ハンドラに前処理を追加したい

Tags: python

```
class BaseHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        setup()
        try:
            handle()
        finally:
            finish()

    def setup(self):
        pass

    def handle(self):
        pass

    def finish(self):
        pass
```

の `handle` に前処理を追加し，継承先では前処理が行われた状態で `handle` の処理を開始したいです。この場合は，どのように記述すればよいでしょうか。

具体的には，

```
class MessageHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        with pickle.loads(self.request.recv(1024)) as message:
            pass
```

を継承し，

```
class ChildMessageHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        if isinstance(massage, Message):
            print(message.text)
```

というような使い方をしたいです。`setattr` を使って前処理の結果を属性に加えるなども考えています。

この場合，どのように記述するのが適切でしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

定義している`MessageHandler`を継承して、そこで定義しているhandle()内のものを実行したあと、追加処理を行いたいのであれば、`super()`を使用できますが、親クラスに定義している尾オブジェクトが渡されないですね。`._message`とかに保存したりできると思いますが、呼ばれる準備によってその値が変われる可能性が高いですね。

なので、別メッソッドを用意すればいいかもしれません。
こちらはどうでしょうか？

```
class MessageHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def _prepare_message(self):
        return pickle.loads(self.request.recv(1024))

class ChildMessageHandler(MessageHandler):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        message = self._prepare_message()
        if isinstance(message, Message):
            print(message.text)
```

`super()`を使った例：

```
class ChildMessageHandler(MessageHandler):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().handle(*args, **kwargs)  # 親のhandle()を実行
        #　続きのコードはこちら
```